Can and do free ultrafilters have the fixed point property?
For a free ultrafilter $\mathcal F$ over the set $X$, can there exist a bijection $h:X\rightarrow X$ such that $h(\mathcal F)=\mathcal F$ but $h(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in X$? Must there exist such a bijection?
This question is motivated by the subject of door spaces in topology and the article Door Spaces are Identifiable, but its core issue does directly not depend on topology. One of the main results of the paper delineates the three possibilities for a connected door space: that being an included point space, an excluded point space, or a free ultrafilter space. The first two can be readily shown to have the fixed-point property, but whether or not the last does has eluded me.

You already have an affirmative answer but even more is true. If $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter on $X$ and $h:X\to X$ is a function (not necessarily a bijecton) such that $h(\mathcal F)=\mathcal F$, then ${x\in X:h(x)=x}\in \mathcal F$. (The definition of $h(\mathcal F)$ for general $h$ is ${A:h^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal F}$.

Let $\mathcal F$ be an ultrafilter on $X$,
$h: X \rightarrow X$ a bijection such that
$h(F) \in \mathcal F$ for all $F \in \mathcal F$.

Then $h$ has a fixed-point.
PROOF. It is easy to see that also
$h^{-1}(F) \in \mathcal F$ for all $F \in \mathcal F$, since $\mathcal F$ is ultrafilter.

Define $\mathcal U = \{U \subset X: U \cap h(U) = \emptyset\}$.
By Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal U$ contains a maximal element $U$.

It follows $U \notin \mathcal F$, hence $h(U) \notin \mathcal F$,
$h^{-1}(U) \notin \mathcal F$.
Since $\mathcal F$ is ultrafilter, $U \cup h(U) \cup h^{-1}(U) \notin \mathcal F$.
Thus, pick $x \in X \setminus (U \cup h(U) \cup h^{-1}(U))$.
By maximality of $U$,
$\emptyset \neq (U \cup \{x \}) \cap h(U \cup \{x \}) \\ \space
= (U \cap h(U)) \cup (U \cap \{h(x)\}) \cup (\{x\} \cap h(U))
\cup (\{x\} \cap \{h(x)\})  \\ \space
= \{x\} \cap \{h(x)\}
$
Hence, $x = h(x)$.
Note, that this holds for a fixed ultrafilter as well.
But this case is trivial, anyway:
Let $\{x\} \in \mathcal F$, then $\{h(x)\} \in \mathcal F$,
hence $  \{x\} = \{h(x)\}$.
